# What does がち mean here?

Tags: meaning

[image]

> はやいもんがち！

From context, I'm guessing 「もん」 is explanatory 「も」+ emphasis particle「の」, and 「がち」 might be related to winner (because the next line is "Ready.. go!" like a race).  Is it 連濁 + 勝ち【かち】?  Though the 勝ち【がち】 I'm familiar with means "prone to".

Comment: Why not try a dictionary first? https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%97%A9%E3%81%84%E8%80%85%E5%8B%9D%E3%81%A1/ and an English one: https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E6%97%A9%E3%81%84%E8%80%85%E5%8B%9D%E3%81%A1

Comment: @macraf  Thank you so much for the answer.  I did try to do that first.  I apologize if my question was dumb.  I initially searched for がち in the dictionary, because I thought I knew the word 早い and seen もん before, and it was what seemed unknown to me.  But nothing in がち made sense, so I next tried to search English words I thought would fix the context like "win", "victory".   It did not cross my mind to think it was a set phrase.

Comment: You can always try Google Search https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5vzF.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

がち here is　勝ち, that is, win. As usually in Japanese, when you combine words, the first syllable of the second word can change into the  濁点｛だくてん｝ form, that is, か becomes が.

もん is a colloquial way of saying 者｛もの｝, that is, person. For example, 田舎モン, meaning person from the countryside.

The full phrase is thus:

```
早｛はや｝い者｛もの｝勝｛が｝ち
```

and it simply means that the person that is first, wins.

Comment: Maybe "The quick(er) person wins"? It seems to me Yotsuba is saying that the more one is quick, the more things they eats.

Comment: Yes, in this particular scenario quicker might be more appropriate.